# `qr.qy()` function in R

Tags: r, function

I can't find documentation as to the exact operation of this function. I have a QR factorization of a matrix `X`:

```
X = matrix(c(1,1,1,1,-1.5,-0.5,0.5,1.5,2.25,0.25,0.25, 2.25,-3.275,-0.125,0.125,3.375), 
nrow=4, byrow=F)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]   [,4]
[1,]    1 -1.5 2.25 -3.375
[2,]    1 -0.5 0.25 -0.125
[3,]    1  0.5 0.25  0.125
[4,]    1  1.5 2.25  3.375
```

The function `qr(X)` yields a list:

```
$qr (rounding output)
     [,1]       [,2]          [,3]          [,4]
[1,] -2.0          0          -2.5             0
[2,]  0.5     -2.236             0        -4.583
[3,]  0.5      0.447             2             0 
[4,]  0.5      0.894        -0.929        -1.341

$rank
[1] 4

$qraux
[1] 1.500000 1.000000 1.368524 1.341641

$pivot
[1] 1 2 3 4

attr(,"class")
[1] "qr"
```

I select the diagonal elements of `qr(X)$qr`, which I name `z`:

```
z = qr(X)$qr
z = Q * (row(Q) == col(Q))

     [,1]      [,2] [,3]      [,4]
[1,]   -2  0.000000    0  0.000000
[2,]    0 -2.236068    0  0.000000
[3,]    0  0.000000    2  0.000000
[4,]    0  0.000000    0 -1.341641
```

So far, so good. Now the next call I don't understand:

```
(raw = qr.qy(qr(X), z))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1 -1.5    1 -0.3
[2,]    1 -0.5   -1  0.9
[3,]    1  0.5   -1 -0.9
[4,]    1  1.5    1  0.3
```

---

MAKING SOME PROGRESS:

So, thanks to the answer and some reading, I think that the object `qr(X)$qr` contains R completely in the upper triangle:

```
     [,1]       [,2]          [,3]          [,4]
[1,] -2.0          0          -2.5             0
[2,]          -2.236             0        -4.583
[3,]                             2             0 
[4,]                                      -1.341
```

The lower triangle of `qr(X)$qr` contains information about Q:

```
     [,1]       [,2]          [,3]          [,4]
[1,]                                            
[2,]  0.5                                       
[3,]  0.5      0.447                             
[4,]  0.5      0.894        -0.929
```

Somehow calling `qr.Q(qr(X))` returns Q using internally the function `qr.qy()` with qr() and a diagonal matrix of 1's as inputs.

But how is this operation carried out? How is the rest of the right upper corner of Q get filled? I think it makes use of `$qraux`, but how does it get to:

```
     [,1]       [,2] [,3]       [,4]
[1,] -0.5  0.6708204  0.5  0.2236068
[2,] -0.5  0.2236068 -0.5 -0.6708204
[3,] -0.5 -0.2236068 -0.5  0.6708204
[4,] -0.5 -0.6708204  0.5 -0.2236068
```

**In short, How does qr.qy() work specifically?**

I just found this: "qy.qr(): return the results of the matrix multiplications: Q %*% y, where Q is the order-nrow(x) orthogonal (or unitary) transformation represented by qr."

Comment: You seem to think that the matrix `qr(X)$qr` is the `Q` matrix. It is not. It is a compact representation of the Q matrix. If you want the actual Q matrix use the `qr.Q` function. See the documentation; there is a link to `qr.Q` on the help page for the `qr` function. Just do `Q <- qr.Q(qr(X))` instead of what you are doing and then do `Q %*% z`.

Comment: No it doesn't generate the `Q`. It uses special lapack routines to do the multiplication without generating an explicit `Q`.

Comment: Thank you. So when you say that it doesn't generate Q, you mean that `qr.qy()` does not generate Q, correct? So it sort of bypasses Q altogether, but the result after it multiplies Q and z is identical as if it had used Q? Is there any way I could convince you to write a formal answer?

Comment: You seem to have edited the original question in such a way that `Q` is no longer generated. Shouldn't `z = qr(X)$qr` actually be `Q = qr(X)$qr`? I'll see what I can do about composing a formal answer without making it too long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The matrix `Q` from a QR decomposition is only implicit in the return value of the function `qr`.
The list element `qr` is a compact representation of the Q matrix; 
it is contained in the lower triangular part of list element `qr` and in the vector `qraux`.
The upper triangular matrix `R` of a QR decomposition is the upper triangular part of the list element `qr` in the return value.

The R function `qr.qy` after some intermediate steps eventually calls the Lapack subroutine `dormqr`, which does NOT generate the `Q` matrix explicitly.
It uses the information contained in list elements `qr` and `qraux`. 
See http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/da/d82/dormqr_8f.html .

So `qr.qy` does NOT transform the compact form of `Q` into the actual `Q`. 
It uses the compact form to compute `Q %*% z`.

The R function `qr.Q` (which you have done) uses `qr.qy` with a diagonal matrix with 1's on the diagonals to generate `Q`.

Why is it done like this? For efficiency reasons.

With the following code you can check this:

```
library(rbenchmark)

benchmark(qr.qy(XQR,z), {Q <- qr.Q(qr(X)); Q %*% z},  { Q %*% z},
          replications=10000, 
          columns=c("test","replications","elapsed","relative")  )
```

with output

```
                                     test replications elapsed relative
3                           {    Q %*% z}        10000   0.022    1.000
2       {    Q <- qr.Q(qr(X));   Q %*% z}        10000   0.486   22.091
1                           qr.qy(XQR, z)        10000   0.152    6.909
```

Lesson: only generate `Q` if you really need it in explicit form and if you need to generate it many times with different input matrices.
If `Q` is fixed and doesn't change then you can use  `Q %*% z`.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much. I didn't realize you had gone ahead and answered my question. Do you happen to have any references or possibly some additional words... I'm trying really hard to find out how to generate this "compact Q" matrix.

Comment: For instance, I wonder if [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=iIOhAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA241&lpg=PA241&dq=linear+algebra+and+matrix+analysis+for+statistics+reflectors&source=bl&ots=eZDhKU8BJO&sig=MPCJuWXpWSBJC9_ohHBI6UX-xJ0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjshNX9p4XMAhUEVT4KHRzkDPQQ6AEIMTAD#v=onepage&q=reflectors&f=false) contains a good explanation of these "reflectors"...

Comment: For instance, and just to focus my study, are any of the matrices (T or V,...) mentioned [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node69.html) the "compact form" that you make reference to. The link you include is so code heavy that I can't follow.

Comment: More or less. See [Wikipedia QR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) for explanation and references. Any good book on linear algebra should give an explanation. E.g. Golub and van Loan: Matrix Computations. The link I included is  a link to the Lapack code which is what R is using.

Comment: I posted a bounty in the hope that I would entice you to add additonal computational/mathematical detail. I have articles, looked at your links, etc. but I'm still working towards it...

Comment: The QR-factorization used in lm() (linear regression estimate) is a FORTRAN subroutine. So it is clear why the binding of FORTRAN-libraries is essential for the reliability of R: R can use the long tested subroutines of FORTRAN (as also other number crunchers). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function

Comment: @jogo  Can you give an example where qr.qy() would be used?

Comment: @AntoniParellada To understand how qr.qy() intern works, you have to look at the QR-decomposition itself https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/appl/dqrdc2.f In 1978 memory was expensive, so the QR-decomposition tries to work inplace. Not the matrix Q is stored but vectors, which allow to reconstruct Q. These vectors have some values 0. This property is used to store the triangle R and the vectors in one rectangular matrix.

Comment: @jogo The historical reference is very enlightening. Please note that I have made inroads into understanding the general concept, as in [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/207128/67822). I was looking for a similar dissection exercise on specifically qr.qy().